# JQuery Help: toggle() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use JQuery toggle functionality, but not able to use properly. Instead of smooth slide up and down, it goes very fast and not in an animated manner.
I want to achieve sliding effect in my code, like [this](http://www.networksolutions.com/design-develop/design-services.jsp) has (Please see Website Design, Redesign Services slider):

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
     <div class="jquery_inner_mid">
            <div class="main_heading">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="features.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>
            </div>

            <div class="plus_sign">
                <img id="imgFeaturesEx" src="images/plus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" />
                <img id="imgFeaturesCol" src="images/minus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></div>
            <div class="toggle_container">
                <div id="divMain" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jquery_inner_mid">
            <div class="main_heading">
                <img src="About.jpg" alt="" title="" /></div>
            <div class="plus_sign">
                <img id="imgTechnoEx" src="images/plus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" />
                <img id="imgTechnoCol" src="images/minus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></div>
            <div class="toggle_container">
                <div id="divTechnossus" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(function() {

            document.getElementById('imgFeaturesCol').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('imgTechnoCol').style.display = 'none';


            $('#imgFeaturesEx').click(function() {


                $.getJSON("/Visitor/GetFeatureInfo", null, function(strInfo) {
                    document.getElementById('divMain').innerHTML = strInfo;
                });
                $("#divMain").toggle("slow");
                document.getElementById('imgFeaturesEx').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('imgFeaturesCol').style.display = 'block';
            });
            $('#imgFeaturesCol').click(function() {
                document.getElementById('divMain').innerHTML = "";
                $("#divMain").toggle("slow");
                document.getElementById('imgFeaturesCol').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('imgFeaturesEx').style.display = 'block';
            });

            $('#imgTechnoEx').click(function() {
                $.getJSON("/Visitor/GetTechnossusInfo", null, function(strInfo) {
                    document.getElementById('divTechnossus').innerHTML = strInfo;
                });
                $("#divTechnossus").slideToggle("slow");
                document.getElementById('imgTechnoEx').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('imgTechnoCol').style.display = 'block';
            });
            $('#imgTechnoCol').click(function() {
                document.getElementById('divTechnossus').innerHTML = "";
                $("#divTechnossus").slideToggle("slow");
                document.getElementById('imgTechnoCol').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('imgTechnoEx').style.display = 'block';
            });
  });
```

Edit: I also want to optimize this code (coz code is not very clean + number of line may also be reduce). I don't know about the correct coding standards for JQuery. I'm very new in JQuery guys, so please show me the right path so that I can optimize this stupid code.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen so many calls to `getElementById` with `jQuery` included in my life.

Comment: You should REALLY cache the DOM elements in variables... This must be super slow.

Comment: @Coronatus: I really don't know about this thing (cache the DOM elements in varaiables). Can you please explain me a little bit or provide me a good link regarding this concept. So that I don't repeat this mistake again. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not resist optimizing your code for use with `jQuery`.

It puzzled me as to why you had all those `getElementById` calls in there when you were **already including jQuery**

Try this:

```
( function() {
        $( [ '#imgFeaturesCol', '#imgTechnoCol' ] ).hide();

        $('#imgFeaturesEx').click(function() {
            $.getJSON("/Visitor/GetFeatureInfo", null, function(strInfo) {
                $( '#divMain' ).html( strInfo )
                               .slideToggle( "slow" );
            });
            $( '#imgFeaturesEx' ).hide();
            $( '#imgFeaturesCol' ).show();
        });
        $('#imgFeaturesCol').click(function() {
            $( '#divMain' ).html( "" )
                           .slideToggle( "slow" );
            $( '#imgFeaturesCol' ).hide();
            $( '#imgFeaturesEx' ).show();
        });

        $('#imgTechnoEx').click(function() {
            $.getJSON("/Visitor/GetTechnossusInfo", null, function(strInfo) {
               $( '#divTechnossus').html( strInfo )
                                   .slideToggle( "slow" );
            });
            $( '#imgTechnoEx' ).hide();
            $( '#imgTechnoCol' ).show();
        });
        $('#imgTechnoCol').click(function() {
            $( '#divTechnossus').html( "" )
                                .slideToggle( "slow" );
            $( '#imgTechnoCol' ).hide();
            $( '#imgTechnoEx' ).show();            
        });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jacob, but this is not working properly. My div is sliding down on the click of slide button, but after that suddenly data div disappears. Means sliding down is perfect but div (in which data is loading , here #divMain) is not visible after that.

Comment: @John, which button are you talking about?

Comment: On imgFeaturesEx click (i.e on $('#imgFeaturesEx').click())

Answer (score 2):

Use `slideToggle('slow');` intead of `toggle();`

Comment: Also consider to put the code's slideToggle() part into the callback function of $.getJSON().

Answer (score 0):

Jacob Relkin has given you a good alternative for your code, I take the opportunity to give to the viewers of this thread some rules to the passage from javascript coding to jquery coding:

1-replace all `document.getElementById('element')` by `$('element')`

2-for all css styles, you use the function  `$('element').css("name","value");`

3-for the hide and show on a same element, you can use the `toggle` or `slideToggle` function and theirs effects (slow, fast..)